# Check geometries in QGIS for multiple KML Files all at once in R or Python?

Tags: qgis, python, r, geometry

I am very new to GIS analysis so please bear with me.

I have 2000 KML files.

I am currently using QGIS Check Geometries function to generate the error report that consists of the following.

[image]

- A CSV File
- A Geopackage file
- A Shapefile

Is it possible to do this in R or in Python for all 2000 KML files at once?

Comment: It should be possible to incoorporate the tool in a graphical model and then batch execute the model.

Comment: Can you show me how please? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please refer to chapters 18.17 and 18.26 of the [QGIS-documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/index.html).

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for that. However, its very confusing for me. Would you mind explaining it please?

Comment: How about you have a look at the modeller first and then come back with specific questions?

Comment: OK sure I will thanks